# How to disable list item of dropdown in angular js using ng-disable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

this is my html file.this is my dropdown having two listitems password reset and send activation email i want to disable reset password

```
        <div class="active-send-select" pull-left btn-group title="{{::'title.active.filter' | translate}}">
                            <button class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.SENT">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                                <span class="action-button-text">{{::'label.button.send' | translate}}</span>
                                <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right" style="margin-top:-20px;"></i>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-state">
                                <li ng-class="abc"><a href="" ng-click="sendActivationNotification()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Complete'}">{{::'label.dropdown.sendActivation' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                                <li class="test-dropdown">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="onSendPasswordReset()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Notified' || 'Added'}">{{::'label.dropdown.resetPassword' | translate}}</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> i did this wid ng-class a su told now its showing gray color and but still m able to click on the password reset list item and it is redirecting to password reset page.


    CSS code

     .resettest{
                 color: darkgray;
                 cursor: not-allowed;
             }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this without a custom $scope function:

```
<li ng-disabled="currentState === 'Not ready'"></li>
```

If that condition evaluates to `true` then disabled will be true. However seeing as you're putting this on a `li` element I don't think anything will happen. You'd be better off putting this condition on a `button` element.

**EDIT:**

The problem here is that disabled attributes have no effect on `li` elements. If you want to show that that list item is disabled you will need to apply either a class or a style, using `ng-class` or `ng-style` respectively.

Comment: Define 'working'. What are you expecting to happen when the condition is true? As I say in my answer, nothing will happen when you have a `disabled` property on a `li` element. Test it on a `button` element instead.

Comment: I have a button named as send i.e is a dropdown button having two options 1. send activation email and 2. Reset Password i want to disable send activation list item when currentState = 'Not ready'

Comment: I understand. In that case you're better off using `ng-class` with a class that will make your text greyed out, because `ng-disabled` only works on buttons and other inputs. It will not do anything on a `li` item.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. Please mark the answer as accepted if you feel it helped.

Comment: Thank you kindly :)

Comment: need your help again

Comment: Ok.... Probably best to create a new question and put the link in a comment here so i can take a look :)

Comment: I saw. You've edited the code but it's unclear what the question is. Please create a new question for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770993/how-to-disable-list-item-of-dropdown-in-angular-js-using-ng-class

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
isSelectDisabled() {
  if (this.currentState === 'not ready') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<li ng-disabled="vm.isSelectDisabled()"></li>
```

This assume you use *vm* ofc.

Comment: <li class="disabled"><a href="" ng-click="openConfirmationModal()">{{::'label.dropdown.sendActivation' |
                                         translate}}</a></li>
        <li> when m doing this it is getting disabled but how can i add condition into it i.e it should get disable if {{currentState == 'Not ready}}