# How to disable list item of dropdown in angular js using ng-class

Tags: angularjs

this is my html file.this is my dropdown having two listitems password reset and send activation email i want to disable reset password. i did this wid ng-class a su told now its showing gray color and but still m able to click on the password reset list item and it is redirecting to password reset page.

```
 <div class="active-send-select" pull-left btn-group title="{{::'title.active.filter' | translate}}">
                            <button class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.SENT">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                                <span class="action-button-text">{{::'label.button.send' | translate}}</span>
                                <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right" style="margin-top:-20px;"></i>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-state">
                                <li ng-class="abc"><a href="" ng-click="sendActivationNotification()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Complete'}">{{::'label.dropdown.sendActivation' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                                <li class="test-dropdown">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="onSendPasswordReset()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Notified' || 'Added'}">{{::'label.dropdown.resetPassword' | translate}}</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 


    CSS code

     .resettest{
                 color: darkgray;
                 cursor: not-allowed;
             }
```

solution

```
<div class="active-send-select" pull-left btn-group title="{{::'title.active.filter' | translate}}">
                        <button class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.SENT">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                            <span class="action-button-text">{{::'label.button.send' | translate}}</span>
                            <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right" style="margin-top:-20px;"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-state">
                            <li ng-class="abc"><a href="" ng-click="userstatus == 'Complete'||sendActivationNotification()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Complete'}">{{::'label.dropdown.sendActivation' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                            <li class="test-dropdown">
                                <a href="" ng-click="userstatus == 'Notified' || 'Added'|| onSendPasswordReset()"><span ng-class="{resettest: userstatus == 'Notified' || 'Added'}">{{::'label.dropdown.resetPassword' | translate}}</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code.

Comment: i solved it thanks a lot...:)

Comment: Using ng-disabled ?

Comment: using coondition in ng-click...